# How do I parse an ISO 8601 formatted duration using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an ISO 8601 formatted duration, for eg: PT5M or PT120S.

Is there any way I can parse these using moment.js and fetch the number of minutes specified in the duration?

Thank you!

PS: I looked at [Parse ISO 8601 durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886140/parse-iso-8601-durations)
and [Convert ISO 8601 time format into normal time duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093071/convert-iso-8601-time-format-into-normal-time-duration)

but was keen to know if this was do-able with moment.

Comment: Did you check their documentation? I don't see ISO8601 duration parsing there http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

moment *does* [parse ISO-formatted durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) out of the box with the `moment.duration` method:

```
moment.duration('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S')
```

The [regex is gnarly](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/000ac1800e620f770f4eb31b5ae908f6167b0ab2/src/lib/duration/create.js#L16-L17), but supports a number of edge cases and is pretty thoroughly [tested](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/test/moment/duration.js#L245).

Comment: It indeed does. The only thing mentioned in the docs is `duration.toJSON()` returns the ISO format, but it works in both directions.

Comment: Additionally, `duration.toString()` and `duration.toISOString()` also return the ISO format.

Comment: This should be the top answer! Why mess with regex when a trusted library already does it.

Comment: This should be the top answer, you can just use moment.js here!

Comment: @qrious please accept this answer! This is the way to go. With this lib: https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format you can also format the output.

Comment: momment is deprecated

Comment: momment is deprecated

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't appear to be one of the supported formats: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

There aren't any shortage of github repos that solve it with regex (as you saw, based on the links you provided).  This solves it without using Date.  Is there even a need for moment?

```
var regex = /P((([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)Y)?(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)M)?(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)W)?(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)D)?)?(T(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)H)?(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)M)?(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)S)?)?/

minutesFromIsoDuration = function(duration) {
    var matches = duration.match(regex);

    return parseFloat(matches[14]) || 0;
}
```

If you test it:

minutesFromIsoDuration("PT120S");

0

minutesFromIsoDuration("PT5M");

5

If you want the logical duration in minutes, you might get away with:

```
return moment.duration({
    years: parseFloat(matches[3]),
    months: parseFloat(matches[5]),
    weeks: parseFloat(matches[7]),
    days: parseFloat(matches[9]),
    hours: parseFloat(matches[12]),
    minutes: parseFloat(matches[14]),
    seconds: parseFloat(matches[16])
});
```

followed by

```
result.as("minutes");
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! But I was hoping to have `PT120S` read as `2` (2 minutes). I'm taking the primitive route, stripping the `PT` and calculating the minutes equivalent accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for so many revisions - hope you aren't getting spammed

Comment: As of 2.3.0, moment also supports parsing ISO 8601 durations.

Answer (score -2):

If moment.js is too heavy for your use-case: I've wrapped up a small package to facilitate this:

```js
import { parse, serialize } from 'tinyduration';
 
// Basic parsing
const durationObj = parse('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
assert(durationObj, {
    years: 1,
    months: 2,
    days: 3,
    hours: 4,
    minutes: 5,
    seconds: 6
});
 
// Serialization
assert(serialize(durationObj), 'P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
Install using npm install --save tinyduration or yarn add tinyduration
```

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyduration