# Halo 5 Api Unknown TimeStamp

Tags: javascript, api, date, format, timestamp

So I am currently working with the Halo 5 api provided by 343 Industries. While parsing the data I came across a time stamp that I've never seen before.

> *PT1H6M19.6203713S*

I was curious as to what format it is and if it is possible to convert it using JavaScript. Passing this into the `new Date()` constructor doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be Pacific Time 1 hour, 6 minutes, and 19.6203713 seconds?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, however, I am Mountain Time. I felt the PT could stand for Play Time but it just didn't feel like it belonged in a time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [ISO_8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> The capital letters P, Y, M, W, D, T, H, M, and S are designators for each of the date and time elements and are not replaced.
>
> P is the duration designator (for period) placed at the start of the duration representation.
> Y is the year designator that follows the value for the number of years.
> M is the month designator that follows the value for the number of months.
> W is the week designator that follows the value for the number of weeks.
> D is the day designator that follows the value for the number of days.
> T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.
> H is the hour designator that follows the value for the number of hours.
> M is the minute designator that follows the value for the number of minutes.
> S is the second designator that follows the value for the number of seconds.

For JavaScript you could use the momentjs library, which can parse these strings. See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851832/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-duration-using-moment-js):

> ...with the `moment.duration` method:
>
> ```
> moment.duration('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S')
> ```